# How to query Samza KeyValueStore by key prefix?

Tags: java, apache-samza

Using the Samza [KeyValueStore](https://github.com/apache/samza/blob/master/samza-kv/src/main/java/org/apache/samza/storage/kv/KeyValueStore.java) interface, how do I retrieve all documents with a common key prefix? The keys are Strings, and RocksDb will be the underlying store.

Are there any issues with the approach below using the range method?

```
KeyValueStore<String,String> store = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStore("foo")
store.put("aaa.xxx", "foo");
store.put("aaa.yyy", "bar");
store.put("bbb.zzz", "qux");

// get all docs starting with "aaa."
KeyValueIterator<String, String> it = store.range("aaa.", "aaa." + Character.MAX_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but because the range end value is exclusive, you could also just do store.range("aaa.", "b")

Comment: For this particular example data that would work, but in general, the safest algorithm is to append Character.MAX_VALUE to the prefix string.